# How to get printer dialog in GVim on Linux?

Tags: linux, vim, printing

Sometimes I like to print some code to understand it. Clicking on the Print button in GVim on Linux prints to the default printer with some default settings.

How can I get the standard printer dialog when I want to print from GVim?

This is so that I can choose a printer (from multiple printers available on the work network) and change other print settings (duplex, pages per side, etc).

Answer (score 4):

See `:h hardcopy` and `:h print-options`.

You can set the set the printer using `:set printdevice=xxx` and other options using `:set printoptions=xxx`.

If you really want to use the dialog box you could print to a file then open that file from some other program to print it `:hardcopy > output.ps`

Comment: Thanks! Any chance I can print to PDF instead of PS?

Comment: Just change the extension to `.pdf` and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

To obtain a print dialog upon printing in gvim, you can add the following to `~/.vimrc`:

```
set printexpr=PrintFile(v:fname_in)
function PrintFile(fname)
  call system("kprinter " . a:fname)
  call delete(a:fname)
  return v:shell_error
endfunc
```

Instead of `kprinter`, which is the print dialog from KDE3, you can also use `gtklp` or whatever is the the print dialog command of your desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Vim script available (see [PrtDialog](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=512)) that provides a self made printer dialog. To be honest, I'm the author ;-)
It allows to select many printing relevant settings like paper format, orientation, line numbering, color scheme, line wrapping, margins, font and font size, etc.

There is also the option "Dialog" (see last line in the printer dialog). If this option is set to "yes", the system printer dialog will be opened before printing. There you have the option to further fine tune printing.

Comment: Thanks! The plugin looks great. However, I'm not getting the system printer dialog even though I chose the Dialog option and pressed 'p'. Its printing to default printer directly.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I use this plugin under Windows and forgot that the option "Dialog" works only for Windows (and you asked for Linux). As an alternative you can define a list of printers which can be selected before printing. See `:help prd_prtDeviceList`. So at least you can choose between different printers without setting `printdevice` manually.

Comment: @Ashwin: I'm out of Linux since some years, but as far as I can remember you can get the names of the installed printers via the shell command `lpstat -a`. The names shown by this command can be added to 'prd_prtDeviceList' so that these printers can be selected from the printer dialog.